# SD Card utility to perform clean or long format?

Tags: mac, sd-card

Is there a macOS application to perform SD card clean or long format so the data is non-recoverable?

Comment: What about the built-in macOS “Disk Utility?”

Comment: @JakeGould Sounds like that’s the only tool that’s available?

Comment: Why would you need anything else?

Answer (score 1):

There has been much speculation & guesswork involving total deletion of data.

Apple decided a few years ago that so-called Secure Erase wasn't in fact secure at all, especially on SSD or indeed SD cards/Flash drives; owing to the way these drives employ over-provisioning. Basically, you can't be sure the data is gone just because you wiped it.

The simplest way to avoid this in the first place is to never store any data in an unencrypted form.

Assuming you didn't do this already, then one 'trick' which will at least overwrite as best it can all traces of existing data is to reformat as encrypted, fill the drive with junk files, then erase once more to remove the encryption keys.

[image]

*Late Edit:*
At Erase, there is a set of security options of varying complexities & durations, which are the 'old' secure erase options removed from Empty Trash [I only just realised Apple left them in there for Erase].
After some brief tests, it appears these are sufficient to elude even good file recovery software, available to the average user.

[image]

This still may not be 100% "government" secure, but it will defeat all but those with a lot of time & money to spend on getting at your deleted data. It will certainly put it beyond any of the regular file recovery tools.

To ensure *absolute* 100% security, total destruction of the drive is required.

Comment: "_You could fill the encrypted drive with useless files as an additional precaution_" - this has the same caveat as writing to everything - over provisioning and the logical / physical mapping means that you may well not be touching the physical flash you intend to erase.

Comment: @Attie - yup, I'm aware of that. I'm just running some tests - so far erase/encrypt/erase still leaves fully recoverable traces. Filling with junk doesn't. I just rediscovered the old secure erase options were left in. Running some tests on these too; will add to answer.

Comment: Secure seems 'secure enough'. I can't scavenge anything once I've done that. I'm still for advocating complete destruction if you want to be 100% certain, but I think the built- in tools are 'good enough' for most people's needs.